# While using 2 json (or more) simultaneously my parse didn't work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

I'm getting a json from server.

I can parse only one JSON at time. But when I am getting 2 json (or more) simultaneously my parse didn't work. It couldn't do deserialization correctly. How do I solve this problem?

update:

I'am sending, for example, 5 requests with time interval = 0.1; Sometimes I get

```
{"status": "success", "msg": "Dish1 flagged"}
```

- it's ok. But sometimes I get

```
{"status": "success", "msg": "Dish1 flagged"}{"status": "success", "msg": "Dish2 flagged"}
```

- it's bad, my parser doesn't work. If I received

```
{"status": "success", "msg": "Dish1 flagged"}{"status": "success", "msg": "Dish2 flagged"}
```

I want first json move to trash and second JSON begin to parsing.

JSON structure may be much more complex than these ones. I can control the server and it sends valid JSON.

my network class is

```
-(id) init
{
    if(self=[super init])
    {
        receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [conn release];
    conn = nil;

    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsDictionary:receivedData error:&error];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void) createConnectionWithRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest *)request delegate:(id)delegate
{
    [receivedData setLength:0];
    conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:delegate startImmediately:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is the JSON delivered? do you have control over the formatting?

If your multiple objects are structured as an array `[{"like":"this"},{"or":"similar"}]` you'll probably have to change to

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] init];

array = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsArray:receivedData error:&error];
```

but I haven't used that particular parser, so the syntax might not be right

Comment: I don't think Voloda2 mean's two JSON objects in one response - I think he means when he gets two separate JSON responses it doesn't work.

Comment: @voloda2, can you elaborate as to what the situation is? you are making one request and getting two objects as a response, in improper JSON syntax? (not as an array) Is the service you're calling under your control? if not, maybe you could break up the string into substrings and parse each portion? or wrap the string in brackets to make it an array? Actually, can you post the response so we can see the real syntax you're dealing with? Thanks

Comment: Great, thanks. Since you control the output, just turn your objects into an array, and then you should be fine (or as Jonah suggested, process the request differently so it never returns un-needed data)

Comment: The main problem is remaining. How do I convert this JSON {"status": "success", "msg": "Dish1 flagged"}{"status": "success", "msg": "Dish2 flagged"} to [{"status": "success", "msg": "Dish1 flagged"}, {"status": "success", "msg": "Dish2 flagged"}] ?

Comment: what if you change `[receivedData appendData:data];` to `receivedData=data;` so that it drops the earlier data? But, to answer your question, if you're controlling the output, you just need to add the brackets (always add the brackets so that even if there's just one object within, it'll be an array so that you know how to parse it) and commas (or you could even do it in obj-c by doing a two step process, first do something like `stringWithFormat:@"[%@]",receivedData;` and then do a find/replace of `}{` with `},{` )

Comment: [receivedData setData:data]; - not good because sometimes we recieve part of JSON. find/replace of }{ - nice solution, thank you

Comment: don't forget the brackets too. I wasn't sure how the data was chunked, so wasn't sure on the setData approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
{"status": "success", "msg": "Dish1 flagged"}{"status": "success", "msg": "Dish2 flagged"}
```

Is not valid JSON.

```
[{"status": "success", "msg": "Dish1 flagged"}, {"status": "success", "msg": "Dish2 flagged"}]
```

Would be valid.

Since you can control the server make sure it only responds with a valid JSON payload for these requests. If the issue is that you are concatenating multiple requests' responses together then please show your request handling code so we can help you stop doing that.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change the output format of your server, you can first split your data into an array of JSON's, then just use the latest from the array. Its really easy just split with the curly brackets.